# PostgreSQL procedure: "No operator matches the given name and argument types"

Tags: sql, postgresql

In `PostgreSQL` database I created procedure which looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE creator(ID uuid, EMPLOYEES VARCHAR[]) AS $FUNCTION$
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM SURVEYS_EMPLOYEES_RELATIONSHIP
    WHERE SURVEY_ID = ID
    AND EMPLOYEE NOT IN (EMPLOYEES);
    --
    INSERT INTO SURVEYS_EMPLOYEES_RELATIONSHIP (SURVEY_ID, EMPLOYEE) 
    SELECT SURVEY_ID ID, EMPLOYEE FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[EMPLOYEES]) EMPLOYEE
    ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unique_key 
    DO NOTHING;
  END;
$FUNCTION$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As you can see in this procedure I am trying to `DELETE` some entries and then `INSERT` other entries. I call this procedure like this:

```
CALL creator('99c89a24-fff2-4cbc-a542-b1e956a352f9', ARRAY['NNogerbek@gmail.com', 'IKim@gmail.com'])
```

For some reason it raise error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying <> character varying[]
No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
PL/pgSQL function creator(uuid,character varying[]) line 3 at SQL statement
```

Where exactly in procedure I made error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `DELETE` query, `EMPLOYEE NOT IN (EMPLOYEES)` isn't right. `IN` isn't "unnesting" the array here and you end up comparing a `varchar` against a `varchar[]`.

You can try to replace it by

```
EMPLOYEE NOT IN (SELECT e FROM unnest(EMPLOYEES) u (e))
```

"manually" unnesting the array,

```
NOT EMPLOYEES @> ARRAY[EMPLOYEE]
```

using the array contains operator or

```
EMPLOYEE <> ALL (EMPLOYEES)
```

using `ANY`, where the array is "unnested" automatically. (And probably some more.)

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer! :)